# How to `~\cite{}' an answer from stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request

How to ~\cite{} an answer from stackexchange? Should be cited by the question, or by the user, any ideas?

Comment: I know you have been sent here, but this should go to academia.SE. At the very very bottom you see the license of the stuff written on this network.